# What it means when we say "{something} is a common part of {something}"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What it means when we say "{something} is a common part of {something}"?

like in this context:

> This rule is a common part of logic and is called disjunctive syllogism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, 'logic' is the larger, overarching concept.

When we say 'a common part of', it means that it 'comes up' often when we are talking about logic. The 'rule' referenced here isn't the whole concept of logic, but is an integral part of it

In this particular example, the 'rule' is talking about mutual exclusivity - one thing cannot happen or exist if another already has.

If I flip a coin, it will be either heads or tails
It cannot be both. If it is tails, it cannot be heads.

That is a *logical* concept.

This idea of mutual exclusivity is used *a lot* in logic and we can define it as a part of logic, hence
*a common part*